# Teechart - Adding / Subtracting graph values gives the unwanted rest

Tags: delphi, teechart

Working with **Steema** **TeeChart** graphs. (In particular objects: **TChart**, **TChartSeries**, **TBarSeries**, **TLineSeries**)

My task is to dynamically combine graphs when user selects some of the them, their values are **added** or **subtracted** based on *XLabel* value.

So this is what I get after selecting a couple of graphs and then deselecting them (which does the following:

1. Sets Series with DefaultBar/LineSeries
2. Adds values of selected graphs to the DefaultBar/LineSeries
3. Subtracts values of deselected graphs from the DefaultBar/LineSeries)

Result (logically) has to be 0 for all *XLabels*

But here is what I get:
[image: graph]

Same graph without marks
[image: graph2]

Here are some of the values:
[image: Values]

Can I somehow keep the actual values instead of rounded values (the ones represented on the graph), so that I will not have any rest after **subtraction** procedure?

I could do something like this to get rid of the rest (I know that the values will be big):

```
   //bad solution
   for Serie := 0 to Chart.SeriesCount - 1 do
     for YValue := 0 to Chart.Series[Serie].YValues.Count - 1 do
       if StrToFloat(FormatFloat('0.00', Chart.Series[Serie].YValue[YValue])) = 0 then
         Chart.Series[Serie].YValue[YValue] := 0;
```

But this is not a very great solution - not scalable.

Probably related:

When I select only 1 graph and deselect it, then all the values are 0, the problem occurs when multiple graphs are selected (addition occurs)

Comment: If x=y then x-y=0. So I guess your x values are not the same. But then, I'm having to guess about both your code and your data since neither have been presented. Your problem surely has a solution, but I cannot discern what the problem is from the question as it stands now.

Comment: Value does not change, it is rounded (well, changed)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan values are the same, because when I select/deselect (add/subtract) graphs many times, values are still the same. I believe it is the rounding problem. Another thing is that the values examples I am shiwing, they are insignificant

Comment: Why are you rounding? You did not show any code? Why not? Why are you concealing the details from us? Why am I having to guess? Again, let me make this very clear. If `x=y`, then `x-y=0`. So, if you are really doing `x-y`, then the only conclusion that can be drawn is that `x<>y`. But maybe you are not doing `x-y`. Maybe you are doing:  `z := x + y; t = (z - x) - y;` Are you going to put us out of our misery and show some code so that we don't have to guess?!

Comment: Apart from what has already been said, I believe this is essentially the same as temporarily storing data in a `TLabel` or `TEdit`. I wouldn't dare to rely that the TChart component doesn't do any "optimization" on the values you put into it, like rounding or truncating to smaller types and whatnot. I'd use the chart just for presentation, not for storing values.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful I am passing data in TBarSeries or TLineSeries. It should not get corrupted, i guess (but i am not very familiar with TeeChart components)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That is elementary arithmetics and it has to be right. I am not going to show any code for now, because I believe that the problem is with the component itself (rounding). Since it was not me who wrote that part of code, where graphs are represented individually, I cannot say (for now) if it is the rounding problem (that i think of) or not. And since I havent worked with TeeChart components before, I am asking if it is a common problem or not, thus trying to see if my assumption about rounding is right or not. I also believe that Günther the Beautiful has a point

Comment: I am familiar with Teechart. I've used it for circa 15 years. It stores chart data as arrays of `Double`. There's no use blaming "rounding" generically. You need to be more precise. Don't expect a precise answer if you cannot give any details. Your question is vague and hence the tumbleweed. Is it a common problem for floating point arithmetic to be inexact? Yes. Is that the answer you are looking for?

Comment: If you are sure there's a rounding problem, it shouldn't be difficult for you to prepare a simple example that demonstrates it. A SSCCE is always very helpful both for us to reproduce a problem (and try to find a solution for it) and for customers that usually find a mistake in their final/big/complicate project.